# Is there a way to pass multiple variables,structures,widget data, etc. to a callback function in Octave?

Tags: callback, octave

I was trying to pass data (mostly structures,info from gui elements,etc) but I am having some troubles doing that. Here my example:

```
  function []=myGUI()
     fig=figure('position',[200 200 200 200]);
     SecondS.edit1=uicontrol('style','edit','position',[25 60 80 20],'parent',fig,'string','enter 2nd');
     SecondS.edit2=uicontrol('style','edit','position',[25 80 80 20],'parent',fig,'string','enter 1st');
     SecondS.text=uicontrol('string','no result yet','style','text','position',[20 10 80 20],'parent',fig);
     S.button=uicontrol('string','Giris','style','push','position',[30 30 40 20],'parent',fig,'Callback',{@myCallback,SecondS});
 function []=myCallback(varargin)
    S=varargin{3};
    first=get(S.edit1,'string')
    second=get(S.edit2,'string')
    if isequal(first,'enes')&isequal(second,'gormez')
      set(S.text,'string','both names match');
    end
```

On the above example I can pass the structure 'SecondS' and I can reach the trigger widget's info using 'GCBO'. However I am not able pass data if I have another variable, widget that is not in SecondS or a complete different structure. How can I do this without having to touch the info that I already passed.

Thanks a lot for any kind of attention of yours.

Comment: This code is a bit weird. What's this `function [] = ` syntax, looks weird. Also, is the fact that your edit1 field edits the 2nd field, and edit2 edits the 1st actually intentional? Also, whenever you have nested functions or subfunctions, always put `endfunction` endpoints explicitly to make it crystal clear where that function is supposed to act. Also, always use shortcut operators instead of elementwise-logical ones in an `if` context (i.e. use `&&` instead of `&` )

Comment: edit fields are my mistake sorry, and about function clarification I found that way of declaring functions is also possible but of course yours looks better. The reason for not putting endfunction is that it gave me an error when I tried to put end ,something like " Put 'end' on all functions or none" and I deleted it. I will also check for & and && usage. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Please compare to your code carefully to see what has changed.

```octave
function myGUI()
    fig1 = figure( 'position', [200 200 200 120], 'name', 'Main User Interface' );
    SecondS.edit1 = uicontrol( fig1, 'style', 'edit', 'position', [25 90 160 20] , 'string', 'enter 1nd', 'userdata', 'edit1');
    SecondS.edit2 = uicontrol( fig1, 'style', 'edit', 'position', [25 60 160 20] , 'string', 'enter 2nd', 'userdata', 'edit2');
    SecondS.text  = uicontrol( fig1, 'style', 'text', 'position', [25 10 160 20], 'string', 'no result yet', 'userdata', 'textoutput' );

    fig2 = figure( 'position', [500, 300, 200, 100], 'name', 'The Button!' );
    S.button = uicontrol( fig2, 'style', 'pushbutton', 'position', [50 25 100 50], 'string', 'Giris', 'Callback', @myCallback );
 endfunction

 function myCallback( Hndl, Evnt )
    fig1       = findobj( 'name', 'Main User Interface' );
    edit1      = findobj( fig1, 'userdata', 'edit1' );
    edit2      = findobj( fig1, 'userdata', 'edit2' );
    textoutput = findobj( fig1, 'userdata', 'textoutput' );

    first  = get( edit1, 'string' );
    second = get( edit2, 'string' );

    if strcmp( first, 'enes' ) && strcmp( second, 'gormez' )
      set( textoutput, 'string', 'both names match' );
    endif
 endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Here below the solution I found for my question after searching for a few hours.

```octave
function myGUI()
    fig=figure('position',[200 200 200 200]);
    SecondS.edit1=uicontrol('style','edit','position',[25 60 80 20],'parent',fig,'string','enter 1st');
    SecondS.edit2=uicontrol('style','edit','position',[25 80 80 20],'parent',fig,'string','enter 2nd');
    SecondS.text=uicontrol('string','no result yet','style','text','position',[20 10 80 20],'parent',fig);
    SecondS.button=uicontrol('string','Giris','style','push','position',[30 30 40 20],'parent',fig,'Callback',@myCallback);
    guidata(fig,SecondS);
endfunction
function myCallback(hObject,eventdata)
    S=guidata(hObject)
    first=get(S.edit1,'string')
    second=get(S.edit2,'string')
    if isequal(first,'enes')&&isequal(second,'gormez')
        set(S.text,'string','both names match');
    end
endfunction
```